# how to easily run a sinatra/padrino application on rails hoster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, padrino

is there an easy way to run a sinatra (in particular a padrino) application "as a" rails app?
i guess, there should be some way to translate "rails server" to "padrino start" or something...
(the hoster i'm referring too hosts rails with mod_rails.)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using mod_rails (ie. Passenger), you shouldn't have a problem at all - Passenger can host any rack-based app, and I use it for hosting Sinatra, Padrino and Rails apps on my server. A very basic rackup file is all you need for Sinatra, something like:

```
require 'sinatra_app'
set :run, false
set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production'
run Sinatra::Application
```

The basic config.ru file you'll need for a padrino app is even simpler:

```
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/boot.rb'
run Padrino.application
```

There's more you can do, like for handling logging, but that should be all you need to get going. Your Apache vhost config for both Sinatra and Padrino apps is also simple, and very similar to what you'd use for Rails, eg.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my.app.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/apps/myapp/current/public"
  RackEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

That should be all you need to start - the only major difference is that you use RackEnv instead of RailsEnv.

Comment: I know I'm bumping an aging question, but switching to a [shared] host that supports Phusion Passenger was a game changer for me.

Passenger is a fantastic product!

Answer (score 0):

You should run Sinatra as a Rack

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_sinatra

Comment: would it be possible to write a rack-wrapper, so that any rack app (such as sinatra) could be started via mod_rails? i don't know too much about the internals of mod_rails, unfortunately...
my hoster told me, they configured mod_rails in a way, that just rails apps could be started with it.